# Как проверить пустую строку

Tags: java

Доброго дня. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, красивый алгоритм, как обработать строку на наличие в ней текста, и вывод ошибки, если в ней не присутствует ничего кроме спецсимволов (табуляция, перевод строки и т.д.) и пробелов. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(!"ФЫВА123-.,!@#$%^&*".matches("\\S+"))
            System.out.println("Наш хмель пожрал долгоносик, милорд!");
```

java.util.regex вам в помощь

Документация

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html

Метод matches класса String:

> boolean   matches(String regex)
>
> Tells whether or not this string
> matches the given regular expression.

Comment: Немного дополнил под  нужды    

    if(!"   ".matches("\\p{all}*[\\w]+\\p{all}*"))
   System.out.println("Наш хмель пожрал долгоносик, милорд!");

Comment: Наш хмель пожрал долгоносик, милорд! - ностальгия:)